# How to apply different sherlock themes to different widgets

Tags: android, widget, styles, themes, actionbarsherlock

I'm using Theme.HoloEverywhereLight.DarkActionBar.Sherlock for the overall look of my application
but to me it's all too light (mostly right). For the Spinner I'm using I would like it to use a different sherlock style so that the background, text, menu, etc all use the dark them.

I'm quite new to android I have no idea (and I've been searching around but still have no clue) on how to implement this

any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already said, just apply a style to a widget.

```
<TextView
style="@style/CodeFont"
android:text="@string/hello" />
```

For more information please have a look at [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

If you are looking specifically for the Sherlock styles, then have a look at the code base, that is open source. There you will find all the styles used and you can make your own out of them.

Comment: well, it seems that the spinner itself (not the menu that opens on click) is a 9 patch so i'd have to go and draw those in illustrator. Thanks martin for the input